# Weird 'ChildNodes of undefined' error in IE8 with an AngularJS application

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, angularjs, internet-explorer-8

`TypeError: Unable to get value of the property 'childNodes': object is null or undefinedundefined`

After making a long list of modifications to my application in order to support IE8, including:
running all of the views in their compiled form through W3C validator, setting up [xdomain.js proxy](https://github.com/jpillora/xdomain) to support CORS API calls, making some general restructures, etc.
I was very disappointed to find out that IE8 still throws this weird error at me, while IE9 works perfectly fine.

[Making changes to the Angular-seo package](https://github.com/steeve/angular-seo/issues/11) to prevent it from running when the client is an IE browser.

Any ideas on what can it be?.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that all your tags are closed properly. I just spent hours trying to figure out what the problem was, until I noticed this in my code:

`<span>some text<span>`

I finally realized I didn't close the `<span>` tag properly. After that everything just worked.

Answer (score 1):

Without the code you are running it is a bit difficult. However there is a command to use for debugging. First you need to identify which variable might not contain an object [i.e. 
"object is null or undefined"].
For example, parent, then you can use

```
//next look to see if parent is something
if('undefined'==(typeof parent)) alert("variable empty:parent");
```

Once you find something that is empty that you are expecting to be an object then you can go trace back from there. Also use a browser debugged tool, to identify the line number of the error.

Often if using the child nodes, you may not have the right level or you need to access as an array i.e. you need something like.

```
parent.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].value
```

In IE you are also dealing with unsupported functions. So getElementById will work but some other similar ones do not. Again typeof can be useful.

```
//next ensure function supported
if( 'undefined'==(typeof document.getElementsByClassName) ){
    alert("Not Supported");                  // notice ^ no () required here
    //...add code to handle differently when not supported
}
```

This may reveal if you can use a function

Comment: What debugger do you recommend to use along with IE to get the line of the error?

Comment: In IE I use the built in > Tools > developer tools, or F12. I also watch out for the bottom-left-corner warning !, double click that and it opens a pop-up with details and line number.

Answer (score 1):

IE8 is so old and non-standards compliant it doesn't support childNodes[]. http://quirksmode.org/dom/core/#t70